Circuit for electrovalve using latching relays and two XKC-Y25 sensors
This is a follow-up of my previous post Latching relays for a water pump with two XKC-Y25 sensors. Here's the problem: I have an electrovalve that uses a 9 V DC latched solenoid, and I use it to fill up a tank. I also use two XKC-Y25 sensors (basically they provide a PNP output) to detect the low and high levels of the water inside the tank: when the tank is empty (water below the low-level sensor), both sensors are triggered, the valve opens and the tank is filled. During filling, the low-level sensor is deactivated but the latching relay allows water to flow until it reaches the high-level sensor and the valve shuts off.
The problem is, when I want to close the valve, I can't simply remove the current, but I have to apply a reversed polarity. Following this idea Polarity Reversal using a DPDT Switch, I used another DPST to invert the polarity and this is the final schematic:

Now, in my previous post, @RussellMcMahon suggested adding two Zener diodes in series for flyback surge suppression. I think that I need it only to protect the solenoid (since it's an inductive load) inside the valve, is that correct? The polarity reversal happens only at the solenoid and not at the relay coils (where a single diode should be enough). Do you think there's something to fix in this schematic?
UPDATE:
Three more ideas:

Since the RELAY1 is not driving high currents (just "signals") maybe I can simplify it with transistors?
2)Using an H-Bridge instead of RELAY2 to reverse polarity as suggested by @Jens.
3)When the valve is fully opened/closed, it stays in that position even if I remove the current. What about providing a current just for the opening/closing process of the valve? But only if it's easy (I have a big battery and I think the valve consumes almost nothing in standby).


do not draw lines through components in schematic diagrams

I know it's a mess but EasyEDA doesn't allow to use the "arc" to jump over a wire.

what does that have to do with anything? ... look at the lines at pins 3 and 4 of relay 1

You're right I didn't notice it.  I'm sorry. Only wires with a red dot are connected. If there isn't a dot in the junction they are not connected.

Your sensors seam to have PNP outputs, so I added a transistor, a diode and a resistor to create a push-pull output, that can also sink current. This extension is not needed if the sensor with push-pull output is available.
As long as one sensor output is high, a current flows through the latching valve, the direction depends on the sensor providing the signal.
The inductive kick back is clamped via D3 or D4 while the other coil end is tied to GND by the transistor.
I implemented a 12 V supply, because a voltage drop of around 2 V on the way through diodes and transistors can be assumed. This results in 10 V across the coil, which is a little too much. A series resistor or a lower supply voltage could correct this if needed.
This circuit is simple but not optimal. Latching valves should receive a pulse only to reduce energy consumption, but here the current remains active as long as e.g. the sensor for "full" stays active.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
A better solution can be achieved if a H-bridge driver circuit, as often used in DC motor applications, is used.
Highpass filters made of C1,R3,R4 and C2,R5,R6 create a short pulse at the H-bridge input if a sensor becomes active. So the latching coil will never receive a continuous current.
The voltage dividers avoid a too high input voltage for a typical H-bridge IC.
The two diodes clamp the negative voltage edge at high/low transitions of the sensors.
The capacitor values are just a guess, larger values for longer pulses may be required, depending on the valve characteristics.

simulate this circuit
As an example of such a H-bridge IC I added a diagram of the internal functional blocks of the Texas Instruments IC DRV8212, taken from its datasheet, chapter 8, page 12, rev 8/2021.

The logic table from page 14 shows, that the inputs directly control the power outputs, which is the coil polarity in this circuit context.

Other similar driver ICs I found, which would work as well here, are: TMI8870, A4950, ZXBM5210, DRV8220.

Suggestion only: For clarity it MAY be useful to describe what the H bridge does or show it's internals. Those used to them will understand that IN1 and IN2 inputs cause opposite polarity drive to the solenoid, and this is implied by saying it is functionally equivalent to your  previous diagram, but some may be uncertain.

I'm sorry I didn't quite understand.  So the sensors have an open-collector output stage that can source current by pulling the load up to its own internal operating voltage. It cannot sink current from the load to GND. Could you explain better the first schematic? In my schematic when the tank is empty both sensors are triggered, they provide voltage, the relays are activated and so is the valve. As the water rises, the lower sensor is deactivated but the valve is still opened (latching relay) until the higher sensor is deactivated. The second relay changes the polarity in this process.

@fabius94 I admit, I didn't fully understand your schematic. I will try again soon.

Maybe my previous post can help you understand the full story behind it. However from what I understand, if I reverse the voltage in the IN1 and IN2 of the H-bridge, I reverse also the polarity of the OUT1 and OUT2, correct? So it should do the same as my RELAY2 but with all the protections already built in. By the way, I like a lot the idea of using just a pulse and not a continuous current: at the end when the valve closes/opens, when I remove the voltage it stays in that position (no need to apply continuously a voltage).

I think, we both made a mistake here. As I understand the datasheet, both sensors are PNP, active high and they provide a high signal if they "see" water. So at tank empty none is active, at half full only the lower one is active and finally at full tank both outputs are high. Can you confirm this behaviour or are they internally inverted and provide high if there is no water?

By default it is like you said, but I grounded the MODE pin so they have an opposite behaviour: when there is no water they are activated. When the tank is empty, both sensors are activated, RELAY1 and RELAY2 are triggered, and so is the valve. Water rises and deactivates the lower sensor, but RELAY1 is still activated by the higher sensor (latched). When the tank is full, also the higher sensor is deactivated turning off both RELAY1 and RELAY2. The only purpose of RELAY2 is to reverse polarity (normally is inverted, but when the coil is triggered it reverses the polarity opening the valve).

OK, understood, your circuit will work, the zener diodes are a good solution. If you want to use the H-bridge solution, the mode pins of the sensors must be set different in a way, that LOWSENS is high at empty and HIGHSENS is high at full.

Great. Two questions: are those leds I used to check if the valve is open or closed correct? and then what's the advantage of the h-bridge? I think it will simply substitute RELAY2 right?
